# Not able to retrieve the data from database when running it on real device

Tags: android, database, android-emulator

I m working on an e-learning type of an application where i retrieve the data from the database on list.

It works fine on the emulator,but when i use the APK file of that app on real device,it does not show any data on list, my database is stored in the windows-file explorer-package-data-database-table_name.

I am referring to this site

http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/12/19/how-to-retrieve-data-from-a-sqlite-database-in-android/

Here's a snippet of my code using database

```
list_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, namelist1());

        list1.setAdapter(list_adapter);

    }

    public  List<String> namelist1()
    {
        // We have to return a List which contains only String values. Lets create a List first
        List<String> namelist= new ArrayList<String>();

        // First we need to make contact with the database we have created using the DbHelper class

        Database_helper_class open_database_helper= new Database_helper_class(this);
        // Then we need to get a readable database
        SQLiteDatabase sqlitedatabase = open_database_helper.getReadableDatabase();
        // We need a a guy to read the database query. Cursor interface will do it for us
        //(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
        Cursor cursor =sqlitedatabase.query(open_database_helper.TABLE_E_LEARNING,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        //above query is read all the database column

        // Cursor object read all the fields. So we make sure to check it will not miss any by looping through a while loop

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            String str_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database_helper_class.QUES_COLUMN));
            String str_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database_helper_class.ANS_COLUMN));
            //double str_gpa = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database_helper_class.GPA_COLUMN));


            // Finish reading one raw, now we have to pass them to the POJO
            nameclass nameclassobj1=new nameclass();
            nameclassobj1.setname(str_name);
            nameclassobj1.setid(str_id);
            //nameclassobj1.setgpa(str_gpa);

            // Lets pass that POJO to our ArrayList which contains undergraduates as type
              pojo_namelist.add(nameclassobj1);

            // But we need a List of String to display in the ListView also.
                //That is why we create "nameList"
            namelist.add(str_name);

        }
        sqlitedatabase.close();
```

Comment: Do you see any error in the log? Are you getting a valid cursor when executing the query?

Comment: yes, it is working fine on emulator but not on real device...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late reply, got busy in other application

Actually the data was not saved in the database, that is why i was not getting it on device.
It works now.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlitedatabase.query()` returns a cursor which is positioned before the first record. make sure to call `moveToFirst()` before trying to access any data from it.

Answer (score 0):

verify your database path in DBHelper.class. And after that Write below line before you call while loop.

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

This will point to your first record and then your while loop will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
// Cursor object read all the fields. So we make sure to check it will not miss any by looping through a while loop
cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        String str_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database_helper_class.QUES_COLUMN));
        String str_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database_helper_class.ANS_COLUMN));
        //double str_gpa = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database_helper_class.GPA_COLUMN));


        // Finish reading one raw, now we have to pass them to the POJO
        nameclass nameclassobj1=new nameclass();
        nameclassobj1.setname(str_name);
        nameclassobj1.setid(str_id);
        //nameclassobj1.setgpa(str_gpa);

        // Lets pass that POJO to our ArrayList which contains undergraduates as type
          pojo_namelist.add(nameclassobj1);

        // But we need a List of String to display in the ListView also.
            //That is why we create "nameList"
        namelist.add(str_name);

    }
```

Use the isAfterLast()-method to check, if your reached the end of your cursor.